# members cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, ioc-container, static-members, instance-reference

Why I've got this error by code below on bold lines?

> Member `IocContainer.ShowWeatherDetailViewModel` *(and `IocContainer.ShowWeatherViewModel`)* cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.
>
> <sup>error code: CS0176</sup>

```
public class IocContainer 
{
    public static IocContainer Ioc
    {
        get { return App.Current.Resources["ioc"] as IocContainer; }
    }

    // Some other static properties.
    // static constructor
}
```

```
IocContainer.Ioc.ShowWeatherDetailViewModel.Item = 
                                    IocContainer.Ioc.ShowWeatherViewModel.SelectedVillage;
```

Comment: Presumably your `ShowWeatherDetailViewModel` property is static as well - so you just need `IocContainer.ShowWeatherDetailViewModel`, or make the property an instance property.

Comment: @JonSkeet: yes, but then I don't use the `IocContainer` from the resources in the `App.xaml` file, sir.

Comment: If you want to use a particular instance (e.g. the instance in your app.xaml) you should make the method an instance method, not static

Comment: @ChrisShain: What do you mean, sir?

Comment: As Jon mentioned, you probably have the "static" keyword in the definition of the ShowWeatherDetailViewModel member. You should remove it if you want to access the member of a particular instance.

Comment: Indeed - we basically can't help you without knowing what you're trying to achieve, with a short but complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it by made `IocContainer.ShowWeatherDetailViewModel` and `IocContainer.ShowWeatherViewModel` an instance property.

Thanks to @JonSkeet and @ChrisShain.